# Load a certificate to sign a SOAP envelope in C# with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I try to load a x509 certificate to use in a WCF client. for this i use the  `SetDefaultCertificate` function but this function throw a exception.

```
var clientWS = new WS_eFacturaSoapPortClient();
clientWS.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(
    StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, 
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectKeyIdentifier, "79852b4fab95e8cd1f6e36167bbb895bd4cbe767");
```

The exception:

> Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria:
>   StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType
>   'FindBySubjectKeyIdentifier',  FindValue
>   '79852b4fab95e8cd1f6e36167bbb895bd4cbe767'.

But if I do this...

```
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
try
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(
        X509FindType.FindBySubjectKeyIdentifier, "79852b4fab95e8cd1f6e36167bbb895bd4cbe767", true);
    cert = col[0];
}
//  Cerrar el store
finally { store.Close(); }
```

The certificate is founded.

What i do wrong?, is posible add the x509Certificate2 to the ClientCredentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `FindType` to `FindBySerialNumber` and it works.

```
clientWS.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(
    StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, 
    X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "0cf43655217b8853e2df0b931d2c352afa93d9");
```

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216109/cannot-find-the-x-509-certificate-using-the-following-search-criteria) helped me.